# Windows service compatibility issue(ATL ,c++)

Tags: c++, winapi, com, atl

I have an existing windows service application which is working fine in windows 7 for the last few years.

I am facing some issue in Windows 10 Enterprise. `CoInitializeSecurity()` fails with this error message:

> Security must be initialized before any interfaces are marshalled or unmarshalled. It cannot be changed once initialized

`RegisterClassObject()` fails with an error message like

> The class is configured to run as a security id different from the caller

Even though both are perfectly matched.

I have gone through various blogs and replies about this issue, but couldn't find the solution.

I have created a sample service which has same dependency and same user logon account, but these two calls are not failing at all!

Apart from dependency and logon user account, what could be other possibilities for these calls to fail?

```
HRESULT hr = NULL; 
hr = CoInitializeSecurity( NULL,                           
                          -1,                             
                           NULL,                          
                           NULL,                         
                           RPC_C_AUTHN_LEVEL_DEFAULT,
                           RPC_C_IMP_LEVEL_IMPERSONATE, 
                           NULL, 
                           EOAC_NONE, 
                           NULL);
```

and

```
_Module.RegisterClassObjects(CLSCTX_LOCAL_SERVER | CLSCTX_REMOTE_SERVER, 
                             REGCLS_MULTIPLEUSE)
```

Comment: Please show relevant code.

Comment: Are there any security settings specified for the service in the Registry? They would be applied before the process starts running.

Comment: Hi @Remy Hi,
If I change call with the REGCLS_SUSPENDED flag "HRESULT HR = module ->RegisterClassObjects (CLSCTX_LOCAL_SERVER | CLSCTX_REMOTE_SERVER, REGCLS_MULTIPLEUSE | REGCLS_SUSPENDED); is succeeding, but CoResumeClassObjects always fail with this error message "The array bounds are invalid. " 
I tried to call RegisterClassObjects in different places before this call, but all are vain